# Generalization of central limit theorem to sums of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{X_k^m}$, $m=1,2,\dots$?

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, cauchy-principal-value

Consider this lesser-known fact:

> If $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then
> $$
> \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{X_k}-\mathsf E_\mathcal PX^{-1}}{\pi f_X(0)}\overset{d}{\to}\operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1),
> $$
> where $\operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$ is the standard Cauchy distribution and
> $$
> \mathsf E_\mathcal PX^{-1}=\mathcal P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f_X(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx
> $$
> is the Cauchy principal value integral for the expected value of $1/X$.

This result bears a striking resemblance to the central limit theorem and indeed may be considered part of the [generalized central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Generalized_theorem). Because suitably normalized sums of $1/X$ converge to the Cauchy distribution we say that $1/X$ lies within the domain of attraction of the Cauchy law.

**Question:**
Are there analogous results for sums containing $1/X^m$ with $m\in\Bbb N$? In other words, what stable distributions do sums of $1/X^m$ converge to and what are the associated location and scaling constants?

**Thoughts:**
For the case $n=2$, I believe $1/X^2$ lies within the domain  of attraction of the [Levy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution) so that we have potentially something of the form
$$
\frac{a\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{X_k^2}-b}{c}\overset{d}{\to}\operatorname{Levy}(0,1),
$$
where $\operatorname{Levy}(0,1)$ is the standard Levy distribution. But how to find the constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ is outside my current understanding of the subject.

Comment: If $X$ has continous positive density around zero, then, by the very same Gnedenko-Kolmogorov theorem, the limit is also stable law but with $\alpha = 1/m$, and the scaling is $1/n^m$.